# Drawing Sparklines Programmatically in Laravel Excel using maatwebsite/excel Package

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on a Laravel project and utilizing the maatwebsite/excel package to export Excel files. In my Excel file, I have a dataset that I want to represent using sparklines. The maatwebsite/excel package provides various features for exporting data to Excel, but I couldn't find any specific information on how to draw sparklines programmatically through PHP.

I have already explored the package's official documentation (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html), but it doesn't seem to cover sparkline integration. Is there a way to generate sparklines programmatically using PHP within or outside the context of maatwebsite/excel package? If so, could you provide an example or guide me on how to achieve this?

[image]

I appreciate any insights or code examples that demonstrate the process of creating sparklines inside the cells of an Excel file using the maatwebsite/excel package and Laravel.

Thank you!